# Splitting out $(1-x^4)$, what is this called so I can read more about it?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In my calculus homework I came across a much faster* solution for one of the problems I was working on by looking at how WebAssign (online homework website) solves similar problems:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x(1-x^4)}{(x - 1)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3)}{x-1}$$

What is going on here, does this transformation have a name?

---

*<sub>this is from the problem: $$y = x - x^5$$ with the point, $P(1 , 0)$, where I couldn't find a way to solve using $$\lim \limits_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{(x - a)}$$ so I used $$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$ which required me to build a big polynomial and factor out one of the h variable)</sub>

Comment: If you get $\dfrac 00$ in this kind of rational function limit, it means that the numerator and denominator have (at least) a common linear factor. And it will be $x-a$ where $a$ is the number which $x$ is approaching. So to factor you just divide the numerator and the denominator by $x-a$ (long division). Repeat if necessary.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you undid the formatting of the equation? In general, we try to avoid images as much as possible, since they're much harder to search for or use.

Comment: @user61527, what do you mean by undid? I might have been working on the formulas I mentioned in my context, but as regards the main formula, I just took a screen cap from the homework solution. I can format it now that I've leaned the syntax for this site. Give me a minute.

Comment: Ok, we were probably editing simultaneously then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They've *factored* the numerator, using the ever-so-useful identity

$$x^n - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + \dots + x + 1)$$

Comment: This identity is *amazing,* and not just for going from LHS to RHS--it also is handy if you want to find the roots of the equation $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1=0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. It's been 10+ years since I had precalc in college, so it's sometimes hard to find the identity, theorem, or formula needed when I've long forgotten it.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this identity has a name?

Comment: @WChargin I don't know of a specific name beyond "difference of $n$th powers."

Comment: @user61527 That [gets it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers); thanks!

Comment: @WChargin: I propose we name it "The Best Identity".

Answer (score 6):

It is called factorization. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization